# Caracteres raros al encriptar AES

Tags: encriptación, java-6, urlencoding

Estoy intentando encriptar los parámetros de una url, pero cuando hago la encriptación el resultado es una cadena de caracteres extraños.

```
public byte[] getParamEncript(String paramsChain) throws Exception {
    String key = "urheEW54rere4";
    byte[] clean = paramsChain.getBytes();

    int ivSize = 16;
    byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    random.nextBytes(iv);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digest.update(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clean);

    byte[] encryptedIVAndText = new byte[ivSize + encrypted.length];
    System.arraycopy(iv, 0, encryptedIVAndText, 0, ivSize);
    System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, encryptedIVAndText, ivSize, encrypted.length);

    return encryptedIVAndText;
}
```

El resultado es el siguiente : {ﾶ.ﾷ|ﾡ￦

Comment: Entonces que resultado deseas obtener?, se supone que esta realizando una encriptacion.

Comment: Pues claro. El encryptado trabaja con *bytes*, realizando operaciones aritméticas. El resultado **no tiene porqué ser** una cadena de texto válido.

Comment: eso lo comprendo, creo que debo editar la pregunta para poner mas info, se supone que con la clave el punto de destino desencripta, pero no no puedo desencriptar.